# Magento 2 : Edit Welcome Message For Logged Users

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, messages

In template `/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml` I need change welcome message for logged users. Now it looks like:

```
<?php switch ($block->getShowPart()):
case 'welcome': ?>
    <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
        <span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1'));?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
        <span></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php break; ?>

<?php case 'other': ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
<?php break; ?>
```

How I can get customer last name and gender. In the finally I want to have message:
**Welcome, Man Jon Dough**

Comment: this code not work for me. Have magento 2.2.4 with Ultimo Theme.
I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting endswitch (T_ENDSWITCH) or case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) in /app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Infortis_Base/templates/html/header.phtml on line 591 Can I help me? many thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138210)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138210)

Answer (score 2):

replace `customer().firstname` by `customer().fullname`

Answer (score 0):

Edit in `<span>` whatever you want -

```
<span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1'));?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
        </span>
```